# How to do in SQL: next and privious value with same value of master_id from two rows? MS SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql

Hello every Body

I have a table like this in SQL:

[image: I have a table like this in SQL:]

I need to write SQL query to get the result as the following:

[image: I need to write SQL query to get the result as the following:]

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Please tell us what RDMS you're using, is this in oracle MySQL? MS SQL Server? Or something else? The version is also important

Comment: @Simeon MS SQL Server 2019

Comment: You can use a `LEAD` function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287803/3218652

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL get value from next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287599/sql-get-value-from-next-row)

Comment: @Simeon lead in the second row will return "c" as the second value not the previous which is "a"

Comment: Sorry I should have read your question more carefully, please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Do a self join on `master_id` and exclude rows where the values match:

```
with cte as (
select 1 [details_id], 1 [master_id], 'a' [value]
union all select 2, 1, 'b'
union all select 3, 2, 'c'
union all select 4, 2, 'd'
)

select a.*, b.value 
from cte a
inner join cte b on a.master_id = b.master_id 
where a.value <> b.value
```

Comment: i have more than 10000 record

Comment: Can you post more detailed example data in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Simeon
[SQL get value from next row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287599/sql-get-value-from-next-row)  guide me
The answer will be:

```
select details_id,master_id,value,CASE WHEN LEAD( value) OVER ( PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY details_id ) IS NOT NULL THEN LEAD( value) OVER ( PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY details_id ) 
     else lag( value) OVER ( PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY details_id ) 
      END AS second_value
            from table1
```